# What is this exercise called, and will it substitute for hip thrusts?

Tags: exercise-equipment

The gym added a new gadget:

[image: exercise device]

You lock your shins into it and stand up from “sitting down” holding weights. The weight room is packed and I’m supposed to do hip thrusts, and it seems like this makes up for a *very* similar movement but I don’t know for sure. (Not having to fiddle with padding a bar so as to endure having the weight across my hips would be a plus.) Also I have no idea what name to search for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The terminology**

That would be a *supported sissy squat*.

The difference between a supported and a "free" sissy squat is nicely illustrated here:

[image: Supported vs. unsupported sissy squat, courtesy of legendfitness.com]
*Image courtesy of legendfitness.com*

**Does it replace hip thrusts?**

No, not at all. The sissy squat is a heavily quadricep-focused exercise. In fact, it's what a lot of people use to downright isolate the quads because it takes so much else out of the equation.

The hip thrust on the other hand is a glute-focused exercise.

So bottom line; they do not replace each other. But both are good supplementary exercises to your usual compound exercises like deadlift and squat.

Comment: I have hip thrusts on the same day as (regular) lunges after front squats; from what you’re saying, doing the supported sissy squat + reverse lunges might not be the worst idea then if I wanted to change things up? (The former targeting the quads, the latter the glutes as accessories to the compound movement.) This thing seems like it also helps practice keeping my torso upright which I noticed I have an issue in lunge or split squats. (Possibly also the front squats, since I have more experience with back squats.)

Comment: @millimoose - Absolutely. As ever, variety is key, and changing things up will always be a benefit to your training.